# Mostrar una array desde el .ts al html angular

Tags: javascript, html5, angular, typescript, angular7

Necesito guardar las horas de un día de la semana en una variable. Esta al guardarse y yo mostrarla en el html solo me muestra la última hora siendo que muestra 13 datos, y en el html me muestra el último, en cambio en el la consola me los muestra todos.

Intenté igualarla a `horario: String[] = []`, pero me daba error. Los datos vienen desde una api y los rescato desde un servicio.

Código .ts:

```
horario: String


  getHoras() {
    this.cargamasivaService.getCargaMasiva().subscribe((res)=>{
      for(let data of res) {
        if(data.semana === 29) {
          if(data.dia === 'lunes') {
            this.horario = data.horario
            console.log(this.horario)
          }
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

Como lo muestro en el html:

```html
<span>{{ horario }}</span>
```

Me muestra solo el último dato.

```
service:
      selectedCargaMasiva: CargaMasiva={
        _id:'',
        fecha: '',
        dia: '',
        disponibilidad: true,
        horario: '',
        cancha: '',
        precio: 0,
        semana: 0,
      } 

interface:
      export interface CargaMasiva{
         _id: String,
         fecha: String,
         dia: String,
         disponibilidad: Boolean,
         horario: String,
         cancha: String,
         precio: Number,
         semana: Number,
      }
```

Cómo se ven las horas (horario):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Y qué estructura tiene la propiedad `hora`? ¿Puedes agregar un ejemplo?

Comment: @Lobos ahi edite la pregunta colocando mas codigo del servicio la interface y como se me muestra en consola las horas, soy nuevo en esto disculpa. las horas vienen de una api y son un string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes declarar `horario` como un arreglo y en cada iteración agregarle un nuevo valor.

ts

```
horario: string [] = []

 getHoras() {
    this.cargamasivaService.getCargaMasiva().subscribe((res)=>{
      for(let data of res) {
        if(data.semana === 29) {
          if(data.dia === 'lunes') {
            this.horario.push(data.horario)
          }
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

html

```
<span>{{ horario.join(', ') }}</span>
```

Comment: Genial bro ahi te di el punto me srivio, muchisimas gracias man.

Answer (score 0):

no puedes hacer una logica en el .ts que recorra un for y esperar que al igualar su valor a una variable te imprima cada uno de ellos en el .html, por que en teoria tu `this.horario = data.horario` se esta reemplazando con cada iteracion que recorre tu for y al terminar su ultimo valor seria el ultimo de tu lista por eso solo imprime un valor, deberias igualar `res` que es la respuesta de tu servicio a una variable global `this.variable = res` y recorrerla en tu .html con un `ngFor` ejemplo `*ngFor="let data of variable"` y alli puedes hacer la logica que tenias en tu .ts

Comment: normalmente eso estaba haciendo recorriendo y haciendo las condiciones en el html, directamente con el service pero me distorcionaba mucho el codigo usando css grid de tanto ng-container con condiciones, en ves de ponerme los datos en columna al lado de uno se posicionaban abajo y al lado no se si me explico y en stackoverflow ingles me dijieron que usara mas la logica en el .ts y ahi usarla en el html por que mis condiciones eran absurda en el html.